# Prevent Emacs from locking up on large file transfer with dired

Tags: emacs, dired, file-copying

I find that when I copy or delete large files with Emacs from dired, (i.e. S-c), Emacs will lock up until the operation is complete. To work-around this I fire an asynchronous shell command 'cp/mv/rm ' so that I can do other things while I'm waiting. My question is that, has anyone else encountered this issue? And if so have you managed to work around it? I'm using the latest stable GNU Emacs 23.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same behavior. I think the reason is that Emacs is not multi-threaded. You can find more information [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/NoThreading).

In my opinion it's one of the major drawbacks of Emacs.